# Drag and drop without removing UIBUTTONs

Tags: ios, drag-and-drop, uibutton

problem is i have to touch twice for dragging the button.. when i touch for the first time it makes the copy of button and touches ended automatically.. now what i want is to touch for the first time and drag..

```
point = [[[event allTouches] anyObject] locationInView:self.view];

NSData *archivedData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:(id)touch];

UIButton * anotherButton =(id) [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:archivedData];

UIImage *senderImage=[(id)touch imageForState:UIControlStateNormal];

CGImageRef cgImage = [senderImage CGImage];

UIImage *copyOfImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:cgImage];

[anotherButton setImage:copyOfImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[anotherButton addTarget:self action:@selector(wasDragged:withEvent:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragInside];

[self.view addSubview:anotherButton];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### This should solve your problem,

1) Declare,

```
@property(weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *button;
@property(strong, nonatomic) UIButton *tempButton;
```

2) Add the gesture recogniser to your button,

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGesture = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePan:)];
[self.button addGestureRecognizer:panGesture];
```

3) Add this handle method,

```
- (void) handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {

    switch([recognizer state]){
        case  UIGestureRecognizerStatePossible : {

        }break;
        case  UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan: {
            UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
            [button setFrame:self.button.frame];
            [button setTitle:self.button.titleLabel.text forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [self.view insertSubview:button belowSubview:self.button];
            self.tempButton = button;
            NSLog(@"UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan");
        }break;
        case  UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged: {
            CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:self.view];
            recognizer.view.center = CGPointMake(recognizer.view.center.x + translation.x,
                                                 recognizer.view.center.y + translation.y);
            [recognizer setTranslation:CGPointMake(0, 0) inView:self.view];
        }break;
        case  UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled: {

        }break;
        case  UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed: {

        }break;
        case   UIGestureRecognizerStateRecognized: {
            [self.tempButton removeFromSuperview];
            self.tempButton = nil;
        }break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do like this..

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
button.frame =CGRectMake(50, 50, 100, 50);
[button setTitle:@"Move me" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonMoved:withEvent:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragInside];  
[self.view addSubview:button];  


- (IBAction) buttonMoved:(UIButton *) sender withEvent:(UIEvent *) event
 {
   // You can make copy of button here.. you will get button as sender

  CGPoint point = [[[event allTouches] anyObject] locationInView:self.view];
  sender.center = point;
 }
```

Comment: this code does not make the copy of button on which you have touched.. i tried it before...

Comment: why you want the copy of button??

Comment: because em using it on my custom keyboard.. suppose if you will touch the a button then it makes the copy of a button and same like on other button b, c, d, e, f, g etc..